# Why does AngularJS always fire $digest on root scope?

Tags: angularjs

[Angular docs on scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) state:

> At the end of $apply, Angular performs a $digest cycle on the root scope, which then propagates throughout all child scopes. During the $digest cycle, all $watched expressions or functions are checked for model mutation and if a mutation is detected, the $watch listener is called.

I wonder why does every $apply call a $digest on root scope? Wouldn't it be sometimes possible to detect which scope was modified and call $digest only on that scope and it's descendants.

For example take that controller and a view:

```
angular.module("aModule")
    .controller("aController", function($scope) {
        $scope.increase = function() {
            $scope.aValue += 1;
        };
    });


<div ng-controller="aController">
    <button ng-click="increase()">Increase</button>
</div>
```

Would clicking the button really run $digest loop on the root scope? Why not run it only on `aController` scope and it's descendants?

Comment: Because angular can't posibly know what you're doing in your function. What if it did instead `$rootScope.aValue += 1`? What if it modified the state of an object that is referenced by the root scope, or any other scope?

Comment: because it is easy to start firing from $rootScope?

Comment: @JBNizet: I think I understand. What I haven't noticed is that AngularJS can't know what happens inside any function body; no matter if it's a controller body or third party code. It can never detect which scope values were modified. BTW you can post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because angular can't know what you're doing in your function.

It can instead do `$rootScope.aValue += 1`. Or it can modify the state of an object that is referenced by the root scope, or any other scope.